# Retrieving data from Excel Sheet with Long name - SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to read a value from an Excel file using SAS. This file is standard and will be re-uploaded every day, Thus I would prefer not having to change a sheet name on a daily basis.

The problem currently is, that if the extract has more than one sheet on some day's (It does in month-end and mid-month files), my code fails, as it expects a sheet name to be given. The problem with the system generated Sheet name is that it's too long for SAS.

Here is my Current code (Note that if the file only contains a single sheet, I can remove the Sheet Name section and then this code works perfectly well):

```
libname xl Excel "&full_file_route" header=no access=readonly; 

proc sql NOPRINT;
    select F1 as file_indicator 
    into :file_indicator
    from xl.'Accounts Per Country Incl. Developing$A3:A3'n;
quit;
```

How can I retrieve the data from this source without having to change the Sheet Name?

UPDATE:

I have also tried using a PROC IMPORT, with the same result:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= test DATAFILE= "\\<filename...>.xls" 
    DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
    SHEET='Accounts Per Country Incl. Developing';
    RANGE='A3:A3';
RUN;
```

The result states:

```
ERROR 65-58: Name 'Accounts Per Country Incl. Developing$A3:A3' is too long for a SAS name in this context.
```

Comment: What happens if you proc import, specifying the sheet name (but without the ' $'n business)?

Comment: @Joe I tried running a PROC IMPORT but it resulted in the same.

Comment: Do you have SAS 9.4 TS1M2?  Or at least 9.4?

Comment: @Joe I have SAS 9.4 TS Level 1M1

Comment: Also - is the range limitation (A3:A3) important?  Or do you intend the entire sheet.

Comment: @Joe The range limitation is quite important in this case. The data on this sheet is quite scattered and messy.

Comment: 9.4 TS1M1 I think can PROC IMPORT using the `DBMS=XLSX` option, but I'm not sure if it has `LIBNAME` with `XLSX`.

Comment: Hmm.  Any chance you can convince your data source to use a named range?  Even with XLSX it's not going to let you use the range the way you're asking, unfortunately.  Short of using DDE, I can't think of a good solution that doesn't involve making a change to the file.  If you're open to DDE or using VBA to preprocess the file it's pretty easy to solve, but with just PROC IMPORT I am not sure this is solvable, at least not with the tools I'm familiar with.

Comment: Can you tell them to simply make the names shorter?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can connect to it via a ODBC connection and then use SQL Pass through. I unfortunately don't know the code for this off the top of my head but some googling may get you there.

Comment: Since you are using libname method, after creating the libref expand the "Libraries" folder and find the libref to your Excel file. Expand the libref to see how SAS is treating the long sheet name. Since SAS data sets cannot be longer than 32 chars, my guess is that the sheet name is getting truncated.

Comment: I tried to duplicate your problem, but I couldn't create a sheet with a name longer than 31 chars, either by hand or with code. That limitation is set by design. I'm not sure how your workbook is getting created with super long sheet names, unless it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to read library contents via

```
proc contents data=xl._all_ out=datasets;
quit;
```

See what the dataset names are and there's a good chance you'll be able to get your code to know its sheet.